# Recognize page elements/objects of an android application having screenshot disabled in all the screens

Tags: android, selenium, android-uiautomator

I am using a banking app (Android app). The app doesn't allow screenshots to be taken. When I open ***UI Automator Viewer*** and try to take a screenshot, I am getting the following error:

> 'Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist! Error
>   while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!'

I am using Appium + Selenium for automation.

**Question:**

1. Is there any way to programmatically activate the screenshot
   feature in the app?
2. Is there a way to find the root object in the application screen and
   iterate through all the child objects recursively and print their
   attributes/properties (as PageObjectModel)?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the work-around with the following steps:

1. Open the application
2. use `driver.getPageSource()` to get the page source as string
3. Parse the page source string and identify the element I need to work with. Then store the element's attributes in a descriptive way in the Page Object Model class

Let me know if anyone have a better idea. Thanks